# How to compare two dates with each other in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a standard ISO8601 date string:

```
2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
```

I want to know if this date is older than 10 minutes ago in Flex. So basically:

```
if ("2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00" > current_time - 10mins) {
    // do whatever
}
```

What would the syntax be in Flex? I'm basically stuck at trying to convert the string into a Flex Date Object without parsing it character by character.

Comment: Does the Timezone matter? I'm trying to figure out how to easily convert that string to a `Date` object but at the moment the TZ is throwing it off.

Comment: You may look at the Flex DateUtils library http://code.google.com/p/flexdateutils/wiki/DateUtils

Answer (score 0):

If you don;t care about the timezone i.e. the date string is in the same timezone as where you are running the application then this should work.

```
var date:Date = DateFormatter.parseDateString("2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00");
var now:Date = new Date();
var tenMinAgo:Number = now.time - 1000*60*10;


if (date.time < tenMinAgo) {
    trace("More than 10 min ago");
}
```